# Jquery window resize flickering and wrong calculation on sticky footer

Tags: jquery, flicker, sticky-footer, window-resize, jquery-calculation

I made a simple sticky footer. It makes everything fit nicely when the page loads, but flickers and doesn't put the footer where it should go on re-size. Any ideas?

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

    $(".site-footer").css("padding-top", $( window ).height() - $( ".site-wrap" ).height() - 1 + "px");     

}).resize();
```

Comment: Why not using `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution in terms of simplicity and HTML point of view is using `position:fixed; bottom: 0;`. Did you try this?